# How can I use if else in where condition in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

How can I `make one query` from these `two queries` using `if else` conditional statement

```
// end date Yes inserted....!
$query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE DATE(end_date) != '1970-01-01' AND 
DATE(end_date) < CURDATE() 
AND is_deleted=0 ";

// end date not inserted....!
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE DATE(end_date) = '1970-01-01' AND 
DATE(start_date) < CURDATE() 
AND is_deleted=0 ";
```

Here is my event table.

```
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+    
| Field                   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_date              | datetime         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_date                | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created                 | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want some thing like this.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE
IF 
DATE(end_date) != '1970-01-01' 
THEN
AND DATE(end_date) < CURDATE() AND is_deleted=0 
ELSE
DATE(end_date) = '1970-01-01' 
THEN
AND DATE(start_date) < CURDATE() AND is_deleted=0";
```

Sorry for my English. I don't have much expertise in database MySQL. Please guide a bit. If you need anything else I can elaborate.

Comment: MySQL has [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: `WHERE IF((DATE(end_date) != '1970-01-01'),DATE(end_date) < CURDATE() AND is_deleted=0 ,DATE(start_date) < CURDATE() AND is_deleted=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE ((DATE(end_date) != '1970-01-01' AND DATE(end_date) < CURDATE()) OR ( DATE(end_date) = '1970-01-01' AND DATE(start_date) < CURDATE() ))
AND is_deleted=0 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `or`:

```
select *
from events
where 
    is_deleted = 0
    and (
        (date(end_date) != '1970-01-01' and date(end_date) < curdate())
        or (date(end_date) = '1970-01-01' and date(start_date) < curdate()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `If` condition solve your problem

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE  IF((DATE(end_date) != '1970-01-01'),DATE(end_date) < CURDATE(),DATE(start_date) < CURDATE()) AND is_deleted=0
```